# User with homophobic name

Tags: discussion, specific-user, display-names, offensive

I am posting to formally register my disapproval of [this user's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/93658/anti-gay) name.

I believe it constitutes hate speech. If you look at the comments on this user's answers, you will see that many others do too. The name is already causing a lot of trouble, and the user has not even been around for an entire day yet.

I don't think this site should tolerate hate speech. I think the name is intentionally offensive and the user should be suspended. At the very least, I would like their name changed.

Update: This user is now tossing around homophobic slurs in the main chatroom.

Update 2: This user has been temporarily suspended and their name has been changed.

Update 3: The user has been deleted.

Comment: A problem with a particular user would better be handled via a flag to the moderators or a message via the Help Center to the community team. Meta is better suited for general issues, not specific ones. I have already contacted anti-gay, but that is all I can say about that.

Comment: @robjohn Sorry. I was not aware that was the proper course of action. I will remember that the next time I have such a complaint.

Comment: @robjohn Thank you for that.

Comment: @robjohn A follow-up question: I rolled back the original question and title after the OP changed them both to make them about the user's offensive name. I did this since I felt it was just going to fan the flames and distract from the mathematical content, and that the issue should be raised on meta, not in the original post. Is this the correct action to take, or should it just be flagged for attention and given time?

Comment: @T.Bongers: It is fine to take the question back to its original mathematical intent. This should be handled in general on meta, or in particular by the moderators or the community team.

Comment: @robjohn Though I do not think this was your intention, it seems dismissive to treat the problem at hand (Hate speech? Harassment and intimidation?) as "a problem with a particular user". This is something where the site community should be involved,

Comment: In my opinion there ought to be a filter for user names. I mean how hard would it be to get a library of profanity to filter a user's name during signup?

Comment: As an update, the [user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/93658/anti-happiness) is now named anti-happiness, and has been suspended.

Comment: Hip hip horray!

Comment: as a happy person I am deeply offended.

Comment: Surely A.C. knows that happiness isn't as taboo as sexual orientation. Surely he/she knows that sexual orientation is something of a different animal than emotional state. Surely he/she does, right?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte It is a joke. He was making a joke.

Comment: (@Potato A bad one, at that, since it appears to be ridiculing and dismissing a very serious issue.)

Comment: @Potato, I'm glad you made this public post rather than just notifying the mods in private, because I think this particular issue needed to be put to a vote for it to be clear how the general mathSE community feels.  I appreciate it.  (I actually almost made a similar post about this user earlier today but ended up just flagging instead.)

Comment: Blown way out of porpotion. This community is too old for [trolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(Internet)). No one is anti-gay anymore, it's the 21st century.

Comment: @GitGud Unfortunately, there are still lot of hateful people around. And while I agree that the user was probably being 'ironically' homophobic, that doesn't make it any better. Ironic hate speech is still hate speech.

Comment: "No one is anti-gay anymore, it's the 21st century". The first part is demonstrably false (but the second part is true).

Comment: This case makes me wonder, if my account number is 666 and some Christian files a complaint, will I get suspended for not changing the account name?

Comment: I just ran into [this](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/1235337_660324527321895_961185577_n.jpg).

Comment: So here we have another instance of hypocritical moral-high-ground-soapboxing in the ever hostile propaganda war on sexual orientations (both sides guilty). Free speech anyone? Or does that only count when someone agrees with the majority's ideals on delicate subjects? Tasteless, sure. Disruptive, certainly. It should be dealt with by mods. But this volatile response (particularly in comments) is nothing but the public hanging of those with different opinion, and therefore morally behaving equivalent to the thing it opposes. Yugh, hypocrisy.

Comment: @Lord_Farin No, it is not, common! Plus, "volatile", "public hanging"? Really? *That* seems soapboxing, more than the other comments. (Anyway, I will not continue on this thread.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I am admittedly soapboxing against hypocrisy.

Comment: @Lord_Farin (Typo. I should've said [c'mon](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=c%27mon).)

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I have trouble digesting your point. Are you arguing that users should be allowed to have incendiary and insulting names?

Comment: @Grumpy No, and I believe that was clear ("Tasteless, sure. Disruptive, certainly. It should be dealt with by mods."). I am arguing that there should not be meta questions dedicated to this, and so wholeheartedly support robjohn's original comment. What provoked my rage was the fact that (supposedly open-minded and tolerant) people are comfortable with throwing reason and moderation overboard as soon as sexual preference enters the field, and initiate a public attack against whoever might dare to voice the slightest (ironic?) bit of the opposing opinion. I wanted to expose this hypocrisy.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: the LGBT community has been an oppressed group for some time. It's understandable that the topic brings up strong emotions. Still, yes, I agree that this would have been better handled less publicly.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I don't think anyone's throwing reason or moderation overboard. I tried to lay out very clearly the reasons why I thought action should be taken. You're free to defend such names if you want to. Further, I am emphatically *not* tolerant of ideas I deem to be extraordinarily toxic and without merit, like racism and homophobia. There is no hypocrisy here. I will concede, however, that this was probably better addressed privately.

Comment: @Lord_Farin This is getting a bit far away from the topic of the post, though. If you would like to discuss this further, how do you feel about opening a new thread about what sorts of speech regarding minorities should be prohibited on M.SE?

Comment: @Potato I admit possibly excessive use of hyperbole in conveying my point (which may have harmed the success of doing so). I will not push hypocrisy allegations further, I have said what I wanted to. I also have no interest in a public place for people to show their progressive-/conservativeness that will undoubtedly (and sadly) degrade into mud-slinging, suspensions and whatnot. As for main, I trust that people know it is about _mathematics_. Any behavioural disruptions should be left at the discretion of moderators, if remotely feasible.

Comment: And that's all; I'll leave this thread behind now -- contented. I'm pleased to note that most of its stinging parts have been nuanced in comment discussions.

Comment: At first I've read: user with holomorphic name

Comment: The account has been deleted.

Comment: @leo, holomorphic? No, polarizing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson very

Comment: FWIW - I downvoted because this post (and all the discussion herein) is feeding the troll.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Hate speech is free speech and thus must never be illegalized by governments. That would lead to totalitarian states, a lack of liberty, an inability to look at all sides and correct popular wrong beliefs, and a constant desire to conform while keeping poisonous thoughts to yourself out of fear. However, this is just a math forum where people just come here to discuss math. Does it really matter whether people have a right to say they do not approve of gay people here or not, even as a joke?

Comment: Of course, if MSE says they advocate for free speech, then your point stands, because many companies say they are supporters of free speech while still censoring hate speech, despite the fact that free speech protects hate speech. However, MSE has not made such a statement, therefore their censorship of hate speech is valid, although some people may disagree, and they should since companies are places where lots of people may gather and speak, and controlling that speech may have bad consequences.

Comment: I am using the United States definition of free speech by the way, which doesn't protect child pornography, incitement of violence, death threats, false fire alerts, harassment, but does protect the KKK, anti-gay Westboro Baptist church, and neo-nazis.

Answer (score 33):

It seems overboard to classify the mere labeling of oneself anti-gay as hate speech. Would this apply for example to the username `anti-x` for various labels `x` that can be applied to people, for example christian, atheist, homophobe, etc? At any rate, the more unarguably germane issue is that the username is disruptive and inflammatory, not to mention poor taste. And there is an even more germane reason for suspension still at hand that is unexamined here.

Edit: I agree my given examples are weak and do not have the force and quality of "anti-gay" or "anti-black," but my understanding is that *hate speech* is beyond being factually wrong, morally wrong, or universally offensive $-$ it is hostility, harassment and incitement at *criminally culpable* levels (think drawing a cartoon in the US condoning a black man hanging by a rope around his neck). My impression is that a single username like "anti-gay" or "anti-black" is too passive and not nearly communicative enough alone to reach a level that it can be called hate speech.

It is clear to some of us that the user "anti-gay" is the *same* as the user "Twink." The account Twink came into the chatroom evangelizing tolerance for gays (something nobody voiced any contrary opinion to) to the point of disrupting conversation, and randomly calling others racist, homophobic etc. Here we see an account anti-gay basically manifesting the same exact behaviors but from the other side of the political spectrum. Both appeared in chat within days of each other using the exact same MO to troll (and as Twink this user explicitly admitted to trolling).

The disparity tells us that we do not actually know what this user's opinions about gays and gay issues, or really anything, truly are. Everything s/he says is performance art for the purpose of entertainment, so we cannot take what is said at his/her word. Ultimately, this user is testing us and amusing themselves with our extracted responses, probably reveling in the power of being able to cause such consternation at will. This is probably the most notable aspect of this situation.

Comment: This user was already suspended in MSE's chatroom once by the moderator Madara Uchiha, who said ["Your own site's mods will decide what to do with him when it's lifted."](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/36?m=11071329#11071329)

Comment: In my opinion there ought to be a filter for user names. I mean how hard would it be to get a library of profanity to filter a user's name during signup?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte Yes, I think such a basic filter would make sense to have. For this particular user I think the most banworthy thing is not their expression or labeling per se, but the simple act of being intentionally disruptive, inflammatory and (in the chatroom) confrontational. Even with automated filters this user would attempt trolling behavior, only with slightly more cleverness.

Comment: Re a filter: as you say, any determined troll will easily find ways around it, while legitimate users may suffer from it via the [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).  Surely it would be simpler just to have it dealt with by mods, providing there’s consensus for a simple (zero-tolerance?) policy so that it doesn’t take too much of mods’ time and energy?  If this were a more frequent problem, certainly a filter would be worthwhile, but it seems like it’s pretty rare so far, fortunately.

Comment: I like this for the most part, but the first paragraph is unfair.  Surely the meaning of "anti-gay" is not on the same level as "anti-christian".  That is like saying "anti-black" and "anti-white" are equivalent just because they are two classes of people.  Surely "anti-black" will offend more people, hurt more feelings, etc.  Similarly "anti-jew" is going to be much more offensive than "anti-christian" even if you think the Jewish religion is ridiculous and deserves a lot of criticism.  It's not really a matter of politics, but rather of respect and sensitivity to other peoples' feelings.

Comment: This reaction, this meta thread, is exactly what the user wanted. The troll has been fed a kings' banquet this day.

Comment: @Goos That makes sense. My feelings are that using the term "hate speech" too loosely could trivialize real hate speech, so I had a bone to pick with that, and that was how I originally thought to articulate myself. The nym "anti-gay" alone could at most I think *remind* people that anti-gay attitudes exist, hurtful but not entirely traumatic. | Aside: observe that "anti-gay" is a term used probably exclusively *against* those who hold anti-gay attitudes by those of us who are more progressive $-$ if there were any lingering question that this user is not being sincere in their presentation.

Comment: @anon Thanks for clarifying.  I totally agree with you that using the term "hate speech" was not appropriate in this case.  On the other hand using "anti-gay" casually in this way is practically as offensive as actual hate speech, though perhaps in a different way.

Comment: @Goos: It *is* a matter of politics to treat `anti-X` labels differently depending on whether `X` is a "dominant" or "oppressed" group.  But this is not the issue at hand.

Comment: @Dan I don't think that many people would be very offended by the username "anti-white".  Most people are not deeply passionate about white people being mistreated or hated.  So it doesn't actually have to do with whether white people are "dominant" or "oppressed".

Comment: How do you know what all those people on mathSE have strong feelings about?  This is a site with tens or hundreds of thousands of users from all over the world.  Maybe there are many more people than you accounted for, who are from traditional sorts of backgrounds, nations and religions, different from the "progressive" leftish academics and elites you might have in mind, who are offended by a username like GayPride or SatansLoveChild, and maybe their number is comparable to or larger than the quantity offended by AntiGay.  Neither your views nor their opposites are universal. @Goos

Comment: Speaking of which, there was a very funny user named (approximately) "I am so Gaaaaaay!!!!" who would respond with "I rise above your prejudice" when challenged about the name.  It might be the same person.  Is it pro- or anti-gay?  Who knows. I left a comment congratulating him on the quality of the performance art, which was fairly good.  I advocate HUMOR as the correct approach for dealing with most of this stuff.

Comment: @Goos, as I am sure you know, it is less likely that people offended by those other usernames would make a thread on meta to debate the matter. They may be non-English speakers, or are familiar with the present state of the Western democracies and understand the possibility of a hostile reception and a battle in which they are painted very negatively.  (Those are two reasons from a much larger set.)  The point at issue was not whether people exist who  have strong feeling about 'anti-gay' or any other username, but your distinction between anti-X and anti-Y.

Comment: @zyx In cases where some are hostile to the fact that others are offended, it's obviously a harder questoin, but that's really not the case here.  No one (essentially) is offended by the fact that others are offended by "anti-gay".  On the other hand with "GayPride" you could have people offended on both sides, both if the username exists, and if it doesn't exist.

Comment: There wouldn't be people leaping forward to defend anti-straight, anti-christian, or anti-white either (and there quite possibly would be defenders of pro-X, for a wide variety of X).  To make the case that those are different from their anti-minority equivalents, does seem to require some kind of dominant/oppressed schema to justify the difference. @Goos

Comment: There are presently 29 users who upvoted the question, and 10 who downvoted, if that tells you anything.  The greater visibility of people attacking anti-minority versus anti-majority displays really says nothing about what is "inappropriate" under your definition of offending some large swath of people or their strongly held beliefs.  It does say something about the culture in which beliefs can be expressed or kept strategically quiet.  There are obvious problems with "placate the loudest" as the effective standard.  @Goos

Comment: @zyx, I think my arguments here have been premature and too strong to uphold.  I agree with you that this is much more subtle than I'm making it.  Thanks for the discussion.  Incidentally, I would guess that the 10 downvoters downvoted because of the obvious modern liberal language ("homophobic", "hate speech"); I personally would have preferred "inconsiderate", "offensive to many members of mathSE" to "homophobic" and "hate speech".

Comment: @Goos In retrospect, I should have written it that way. I was trying to be as short as possibly, so it wouldn't be ranty, and I seem to have cut corners a little too much.

Comment: Being "a-theist" or any anti-$x$ where $x$ represents an ideology, a way of thinking like a religious or political opinion, for ex. "anti-christian", is not the same as being anti-$x$ where $x$ represents people, for ex. "anti-gay", "anti-black" or "anti-white".

Comment: @DavideZena True, the examples of labels I gave are not as germane as the examples of labels you give in your comment.

Answer (score 27):

Reminds me of this SMBC comic:

[image]

Comment: +1 In the name of Ser Weiner.

Comment: @zyx: Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal.

Comment: Apparently I am not au courant in matters of popular culture.  Thanks.  @AsafKaragila